# Bootstrap Menu for WordPress (without Nav-Walker class)

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I am working on a WordPress (fully CSS bootstrap) Theme and I am trying to incorporate the WP navigation into it (without using the nav-walker class). Please do not recommend it. I know how to use it. Just don't like it.

I was able to get the navigation working (shows up) but the CSS controlling the style for navigation seems to be off.!

Below is the codes is that is displayed in the view-source of the page:

```
    <div class="site-nav-container">
        <nav id="navbar_top" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark"><a href="index.php" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dragon"></i></a>
        <div class="w-200 text-right">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav main-menu navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
                    <ul id="header-menu-content" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-23"><a href="#" aria-current="page">Home</a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-24"><a href="#">Forum</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-69" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-69"><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-68"><a href="#">Forum</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-70" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-70"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-71" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-72" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-72"><a href="#">Sample Page</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73"><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-74"><a href="#">Sample Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

This is what it should look like for the view-source of the page:

```
            <div class="site-nav-container">

                <nav id="navbar_top" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark"><a href="index.php" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item"><i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i><i class="fa fa-fw fa-dragon"></i></a>
                    <div class="w-200 text-right">

                            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1" id="myNavbar">
                        <ul class="nav main-menu navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="index.php" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item nav-active"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-home"></i>Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a href="modules.php?name=Forums" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-comment-alt"></i>Forums</a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=Groups"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-object-group"></i>Groups</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=Forums&file=search"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search-minus"></i>Search</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=Forums&file=search&search_id=newposts"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-object-group"></i>Newest Posts</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=Forums&file=search&search_id=unanswered"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-object-group"></i>Unanswered Posts</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=Forums&file=statistics"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-object-group"></i>Statistics</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a href="modules.php?name=File_Repository" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item"><span class="menu-title"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-download"></i>Downloads</span></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu dropdown-menu">
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=File_Repository&action=newdownloads"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>Newest Files</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=File_Repository&action=mostpopular"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>Popular Files</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=File_Repository&action=statistics"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-file"></i>Statistics</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=File_Repository&action=search"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-search-minus"></i>Search</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=File_Repository&action=submitdownload"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-upload"></i>Upload File</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=Image_Repository" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-image"></i>Imagehost</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=Members_List" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-list-ol"></i>Members</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="store" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-store-alt"></i>Store</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item" href="modules.php?name=Timeline"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-history"></i>Time Line</a>
                        </li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a href="modules.php?name=Your_Account&op=new_user" class="text-lg-uppercase nav-link m-2 menu-item"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-registered"></i>Register</a></li>


    
                                                    </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
        </div>
```

Comment: what is the actual issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to have the dropdown menu show up correctly with the CSS. But with the different default class and id control from WP and what I am trying to use, it is conflicting. I was able to figured out a few things and able to get part of it working, but the dropdown still not working properly yet.

Comment: OK, updates and changes in what I needed. After I was working on the theme and trying to fix the navigation with the dropdown. I was able to fix a few things and updated the class like "<li>" and "<ul>" for the top-level nav. But I need to figure out how to update and change classes for the dropdown submenu class. Is there a way to do that?